# Combining Multiple Folders with prefix and timestamp in folder name into new folder with just prefix

Tags: batch-file

So, this is a particularly puzzling problem for me.  I'm open to using whatever I must, but I typically only write simple batch files.

I have a huge research project at the hospital where I work, and the data I'm working with is presented to me with a 4 digit subject identifier followed by a timestamp, as seen in this example:

6443_20170419_141200416
6443_20170419_141200447
6443_20170419_141200500
6476_20170419_141200537
6476_20170419_141201112
etc.

I have literally thousands of these folders, and in each of them is between 1 and 3 files with very long file names - the only commonality is the .DCM extension.

What I'd like to do is have a script that will extract the first 4 characters of the folder name, create a new directory with that 4 character name, and then copy any files located within folders with the matching prefix into the newly created folder.

For example, let's say the folders which all start with 6443 have several .DCM files in them.  I want to create a new folder named 6443 (in a different location that the then current directory, to avoid accidental deletion), and then move all of the .DCM files from each directory into the new folder.

I have a .TXT file which contains all of the subject ID #'s that I've been using for various other scripted tasks, using FOR /F to walk this file, if that gives anyone an idea for a solution.

This once is really picklin' my noggin.  Help!!!

----- ADDITIONAL INFO -----
I've been making progress, but it's still not right.  I'm using the script as shown below, but it's moving ALL of the files in each of the folders to each of the newly created folders, instead of sorting them by 4 digit prefix.

```
@ECHO on
cls

FOR /f "delims=_" %%a IN ('dir /b /ad "*_*_*"') DO (
    if not exist %%a MD .\combined\%%a
    FOR /d /r %%d IN ("*") DO (
    copy %%d\* .\combined\%%a\* 
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the corrected script:

```
@echo on
cls

for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B /A:D "????_*"') do (
    if not exist ".\combined\%%a\" md ".\combined\%%a"
    copy ".\%%a_%%b\*.dcm" ".\combined\%%a"
)
```

What I changed:

- the `tokens` option has been added to the outer `for /F` loop in order to be able to rebuild the original source directory name later;
- the directory search pattern has been improved;
- the `if` query checked the wrong directory;
- the inner `for` loop has been removed, because it iterated over all source directories again;
- the source and destination paths for the `copy` command have been adapted;
- all paths are properly quoted;

Comment: Thanks - didn't know about that :)

One more question for you - can you tell me a little about what the %%b mean, and how it works?  I'm adding to the code you gave me to further isolate the combined files by the 2 letter prefix, and renaming them as I copy them...but it's not working correctly.

Comment: Take a look at [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) -- you will find what references like `%%a`, `%%b` mean. The `?` is a wildcard standing for a single character -- see [`dir`](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html). You can of course ask a new question concerning your new issue...